# Joomla .htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I am trying to rewrite from 
mysite.com/pokerbono/xyz 
to 
mysite.com/pokerbono.php?id=XYZ
Here is the code I added in the .htaccess:

> #### Affiliate Links
>
> RewriteRule ^pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]

What is wrong with this rule? I tried like 100 variations and always receive a 404.

I tried each and every variation right now I have in my .htaccess the following rows:

> RewriteRule ^pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^/pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^/pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^/pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
>
> RewriteRule ^/pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Try including slashes on the front:

```
RewriteRule ^/pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**UPD**:

This works in my environment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^qwe/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ qwe.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: i tried each and every variation, right now I have in the .htacces this:
RewriteRule ^pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/pokerbono/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /pokerbono.php?id=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable Multiviews, now it is working fine :)